What are the risks of registering a Resource Provider?
In my company's Azure tenant the resource provider Microsoft.ServiceLinker is not registered. From my experience and understanding the implication of this is we're not able to provision any resource that then provisions something else and ties them together.
For example, the process of deploying a Web App is not able to also create and link together and Application Insights resource. Or, deploying the Web App + Database resource is unable to pass validation and fails to do anything. As a result we're unable to deploy some of the most essential resources in Azure.
The error in both these cases is
{
    "error": {
        "code": "AuthorizationFailed",
        "message": "The client 'me@company.com' with object id 'my-user-guid' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.ServiceLinker/register/action' over scope '/subscriptions/subscription-guid' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."
    }
}

I am an Owner in the resource groups where I'm trying to provision things.
I see in the Microsoft documentation they say

Registering unnecessary resource providers may result in unrecognized
apps appearing in your Microsoft Entra tenant. Microsoft adds the app
for a resource provider when you register it. These apps are typically
added by the Windows Azure Service Management API. To prevent
unnecessary apps in your tenant, only register needed resource
providers.

However, I'm failing to understand the weight of this risk in light of being unable to easily provision anything in our resource groups without IT support.
What are the risks of allowing users to register resource providers and specifically the ServiceLinker resource provider?
